# Folder Redirection log not appearing

Tags: windows-7, logging, folder-redirection

I followed the directions posted on TechNet for enabling folder redirecting logging on the client computer. Unfortunately, I do see any fdeploy.log folder in the "usermode" folder.  Does anyone know what would stop this log file from being created?

I do have another log file, Gpsvc.log enabled and it appears in the usermode folder, would having the two logs enabled conflict with one another?

Instructions for fdeploy.log: [TechNet fdeploy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc727967(v=WS.10).aspx)

Instructions for Gpsvc.log: [TechNet gpsvc](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mempson/archive/2010/01/10/userenvlog-for-windows-vista-2008-win7.aspx)

The clients computer is windows 7 ENT 64bit

Comment: From the first link you posted - "The log file can be found at: `%Systemroot%\debug\usermode\fdeploy.log`". From the second link you posted "View the `Gpsvc.log` file in the following folder: `%windir%\debug\usermode`" so they should both appear in the same folder. Again from the first link "Folder redirection CSE logging, by default, is set to only log errors.". Maybe there were no errors to log?

Comment: @DavidPostill Hmm, that's interesting.  I didn't think about it not appearing because there were no errors.  This came about because we have a user who's "My Docs" wont appear, even though the registry key points to the proper server/location for the documents and the folder redirect policy is shown to have been applied.  The user is able to access them through a mapped network drive, so I just assumed it was an error on startup/log in.  I will keep looking into this, thanks!

Comment: @DavidPostill After looking into this a little bit more, I found that in windows 7 the log file will not appear in the directory in the posted link.  Instead more information will be available in the event viewer under computer management (the folder redirection log to be exact).  I  hope this information helps anyone else that might run across this issue.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows 7 machines, enabling folder redirection will not create a log file in the %Systemroot%\debug\usermode directory.  However, it will enable more information in the system event log for folder redirection.  The below link is the article I found that pointed this out.

Note: this link is in google cache mode due to companies security policy.

[Clint Boessen's Blog](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RQk8xJHMIWoJ:clintboessen.blogspot.com/2010/06/debug-logging-for-folder-redirection.html%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)